# How to insert into sales_flat_order_grid in magento

Tags: php, database, magento, pdo

I've tried to insert some data catch from API array to insert them into sales_flat_order_grid and sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_address.
For the last one I can insert data without problem but in **sales_flat_order_grid** but there's no way to do it manualy or by insert array.

```
Foreach($array as $value){
                $array = array(
                 'status' => $value['status'],
                 'base_grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'increment_id' => $value['number'],
                 'base_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'shipping_name' => $value['name'],
                 'global_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'order_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'store_name' => 'linio marketplace',
                 'created_at' => $value['created'],
                 'updated_at' => $value['created']);
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/grid')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();
                  $id = $modele->getId();
                $array = array(
                 'status' => $value['status'],
                 'base_grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'increment_id' => $value['number'],
                 'base_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'customer_email' => $value['email'],
                 'customer_firstname' => $value['name'],
                 'customer_lastname' => $value['apellido'],
                 'global_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'order_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'store_name' => 'linio marketplace',
                 'created_at' => $value['created'],
                 'updated_at' => $value['created'],
                 'total_item_count' => $value['item']);
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/order')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();
                  $id = $modele->getId();
                $array = array(
                 'parent_id' => $id,
                 'region' => $value['region'],
                 'postcode' => $value['zip'],
                 'street' => $value['address'].'.'.$value['country'],
                 'city' => $value['city'],
                 'email' => $value['email'],
                 'telephone' => $value['tel'],
                 'firstname' => $value['name'],
                 'lastname' => $value['apellido'],
                 'address_type' => 'shipping');
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/address')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();  
                 }
```

Please any suggestion. The idea is to get and save to see the order on the grid adminhtl orders.

Comment: Are you trying to create order manually or update the existing order?

Comment: yes I did and I can do it manually , or update manually also. But no from sending an array is like nothings happen

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me using insertion like this

```
$entity_id =1; 
$entity_type_id =4; 
$attribute_id = 92;
$value = 'red'; 
$store_id  =1;
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('some_table_name');
$query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES ($entity_id, $entity_type_id, $attribute_id, $value, $store_id);";
$writeAdapter->query($query);
```